# Defect Suite Popover

Tags: rally

Is there a way to implement a Defect Suite Popover within a Rally Grid that allows for viewing Defect Suites associated with a Defect?  Currently, only the count of Defect Suites for a given Defect seems available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one took a little bit of tinkering, but here's what I came up with.  I included the full app because there are a few moving parts.  Basically this setup mirrors the way the other existing popovers are built (Defects, Tasks, etc.)

First we define a popover.  I borrowed code from the [TaskPopover](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.popover.TaskPopover) as a starting point and then updated the parentProperty and childField configs near the bottom and changed the columns to be shown.

Next we define a status template to render the defect suite count in the grid.  Again, I borrowed code from the [TaskStatusTemplate](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.renderer.template.status.TaskStatusTemplate) as a starting point and just tweaked it a little bit to show the right data.  There is some css at the bottom of the app to style it as well.

Finally, in the sample app included I add a grid of defects that all contain defect suites to test it.  There are two little overrides at the beginning of the launch method to completely wire up the popover.

Hope that gets you started!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DefectSuitePopover</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {

            //
            //Define the popover
            //
            Ext.define('DefectSuitePopover', {
                alias: 'widget.defectsuitepopover',
                extend: 'Rally.ui.popover.ListViewPopover',

                title: 'Defect Suites',
                titleIconCls: 'icon-defect-suite',
                width: 700,

                constructor: function (config) {
                    config.listViewConfig = Ext.merge({
                        gridConfig: {
                            addNewConfig: {},
                            columnCfgs: [
                                {
                                    dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                                    width: 90
                                },
                                {
                                    dataIndex: 'Name',
                                    flex: 1
                                },
                                {
                                    dataIndex: 'Owner',
                                    width: 90
                                },
                                {
                                    dataIndex: 'ScheduleState',
                                    width: 55
                                }
                            ],
                            storeConfig: {
                                context: config.context
                            }
                        },
                        model: Ext.identityFn('DefectSuite'),
                        parentProperty: 'Defects',
                        childField: 'DefectSuites'
                    }, config.listViewConfig);

                    this.callParent(arguments);
                }
            });

            //
            //Define the status template for the grid to launch the popover
            //
            Ext.define('DefectSuitesStatusTemplate', {
                extend: 'Rally.ui.renderer.template.status.StatusTemplate',

                inheritableStatics: {
                    onClick: function(event, ref) {
                        Rally.ui.renderer.template.status.StatusTemplate.onClick(event, ref, {
                            field: 'DefectSuite',
                            target: event.target,
                            targetSelector: 'a.id-' + Rally.util.Ref.getOidFromRef(ref)
                        });
                    }
                },

                constructor: function() {
                    this.callParent([
                        '<tpl if="this._getCount(values) &gt; 0">',
                            '<a class="defect-suites-count id-{[values.ObjectID]}" onclick="{[this._getOnClick(values)]}">',
                                '{[this._getCount(values)]}',
                            '</a>',
                        '</tpl>'
                    ]);
                },

                _getCount: function (recordData) {
                    return recordData.DefectSuites.Count;
                },

                _getOnClick: function(recordData) {
                    return 'DefectSuitesStatusTemplate.onClick(event, \'' + recordData._ref + '\'); return false;';
                }
            });

            //
            //Define the app
            //
            Ext.define('DefectSuitePopoverApp', {
                extend: 'Rally.app.App',
                componentCls: 'app',
                launch: function() {

                    //Add the new status template
                    Rally.ui.renderer.RendererFactory.fieldTemplates.defectsuites = function() {
                        return Ext.create('DefectSuitesStatusTemplate');
                    };

                    //Register the popover
                    Rally.ui.popover.PopoverFactory.popovers.DefectSuite = function(config) {
                        return Ext.create('DefectSuitePopover', config);
                    };

                    //Add grid
                    this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygrid',
                        columnCfgs: [
                            'FormattedID',
                            'Name',
                            'Owner',
                            {
                                dataIndex: 'DefectSuites',
                                align: 'center'
                            },
                            'Tasks',
                            'State'
                        ],
                        context: this.getContext(),
                        enableEditing: false,
                        showRowActionsColumn: false,
                        storeConfig: {
                            model: 'defect',
                            filters: [{
                                property: 'DefectSuites.ObjectID',
                                operator: '!=',
                                value: null
                            }]
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


            Rally.launchApp('DefectSuitePopoverApp', {
                name:"DefectSuitePopover",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .app a.defect-suites-count {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #337ec6;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```